# Can kubernetes have different container runtimes/version in worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

We have an application that requires a different container runtime than what we have right now in our kubernetes cluster.  Our cluster is deployed via kubeadm in our baremetal cluster. K8s version is 1.21.3

Can we install different container runtime or version to a single worker node?

Just wanted to verify inspite knowing that k8s design is modular enough.. CRI, CNI etc

Comment: In theory, I think can. But things like network plugins might go nuts.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? How did you deploy it (bare metal / cloud providor)? Did you already deploy something and try to solve this? [Here](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-containerd-integration/) you can find an example with docker containerd integration